# Python - Pandas Max Range Betwen two Values in a column that is not a max and min of column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a challenge that i think is a little bit complex to explain.

I have a dataframe below.

[image]

Here i need to get the min and max datetime value for eatch log per user, its not so hard.
However i need to found the max range of time in values of "Time" column for each user and get a dataframe below as result.

Can someone help of provide any guide about how proceed, if there are any pandas function that make it possible for each user.

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you show how you have tried to achieve this in Python? Please post the code with the dataframe and the groupby / sorting / window that did not give the right result yet.

Think about using `df.groupby('User')['Time'].first()`, do the same for last and calculate the difference between the two values.

Comment: I think we need to sort time first to get the difference , check time  of `index` 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understood -- you want:

Total_range -- the elapsed time between the first and last timestamp for each user
Max_range_between_2  --  the highest elapsed time between two successive timestamps for each user.

Based on my above understanding here is the solution.

```
Data:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['USER1', 'USER1', 'USER1', 'USER1', 'USER1',
                        'USER2', 'USER2', 'USER2', 'USER2', 'USER2'],
        'Time': ['11/05/2020 11:01:29','11/05/2020 11:03:30','11/05/2020 
                 12:04:35','11/05/2020 13:10:25','11/05/2020 12:30:25',
                '11/05/2020 12:01:29','11/05/2020 12:03:30','11/05/2020 
                13:04:35','11/05/2020 14:20:59','11/05/2020 13:30:25']})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(ndf.Time)

df

    User    Time
 0  USER1   2020-11-05 11:01:29
 1  USER1   2020-11-05 11:03:30
 2  USER1   2020-11-05 12:04:35
 3  USER1   2020-11-05 13:10:25
 4  USER1   2020-11-05 12:30:25
 5  USER2   2020-11-05 12:01:29
 6  USER2   2020-11-05 12:03:30
 7  USER2   2020-11-05 13:04:35
 8  USER2   2020-11-05 14:20:59
 9  USER2   2020-11-05 13:30:25
```

Here is the code:

```
def tot_range(S):
    return S[len(S)-1] - S[0]

def max_range(S):
    return (S - S.shift()).max()

df.groupby('User').agg({'Time': [('First_time_log',np.min) ,  \
        ('Last_time_log', np.max), ('Total_Range',tot_range),  \ 
    ('Max_Range_between_2_times',max_range)]}).reset_index()
```

Here is the output

```
  User  Time
          First_time_log       Last_time_log    Total_Range Max_Range_between_2_times
 0  USER1   2020-11-05 11:01:29 2020-11-05 13:10:25 01:28:56    01:05:50
 1  USER2   2020-11-05 12:01:29 2020-11-05 14:20:59 01:28:56    01:16:24
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JQadrad replied, `.first(), .last()` should be used to aggregate and calculate the difference. I didn't understand the formula for 'Max_rage_between_2_times', so I didn't write the code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':user, 'Time':time})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
first = df.groupby('User')['Time'].first().reset_index().rename(columns={'Time':'First_Time_log'})
last = df.groupby('User')['Time'].last().reset_index().rename(columns={'Time':'Last_Time_log'})
df1 = pd.merge(first, last, on='User')
df1['Total_Rage'] = df1['Last_Time_log'] - df1['First_Time_log']

df1
    User    First_Time_log  Last_Time_log   Total_Rage
0   USER1   2020-11-05 11:01:29 2020-11-05 12:30:25 01:28:56
1   USER2   2020-11-05 12:01:29 2020-11-05 13:30:25 01:28:56
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# df = df.sort_values(['User','Time'])             ## sorting to get more accurate results
df['end'] = df.groupby('User')['Time'].shift(-1)   ## get endtime 
df['diff'] = df['end'] - df['Time']                ## difference of endtime and time
df2 =df.groupby('User').agg(
    Max_Range_between_2_times= ("diff",max),
    Total_Range= ("diff",sum),
    First_Time_log= ("Time","first"),
    Last_Time_log= ("Time","last"),
    ).reset_index()
```

output:

```
User    Max_Range_between_2_times   Total_Range First_Time_log  Last_Time_log
0   USER1   01:05:50    01:28:56    2020-11-05 11:01:29 2020-11-05 12:30:25
1   USER2   01:16:24    01:28:56    2020-11-05 12:01:29 2020-11-05 13:30:25
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, it's amazing the pandas power.